# Urban Airship Credentials

Tags: node.js, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am trying to use module node-urban-airship in node js to send push notifications. I have setup the certificate for iOS devices in the urban airship account. The node module node-urban-airship specifies to initialize the module by

```
var UA = require("urban-airship");
var ua = new UA("<api key>", "<api secret key>", "<api master key>");
```

I have found the api key and api secret in the .plist file they have provided to download. But there is nowhere I can find the api master key. Can anyone let me know where to get the api master key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't send first test notification from the dashboard of urban airship that is why I was not able to see any setting in the dashboard. You need to broadcast first notification successfully to device to access all the settings and that is how you get access to app key, app secret & api master key under app settings.